"um ein Vielfaches" vs. "um das Vielfache"
Als ich ein paar Muttersprachler nach dem folgenden Fragment gefragt habe, haben sie mir gesagt "um das Vielfache" klinge merkwürdig, sogar falsch, und es solle "um ein Vielfaches sein":

Das Lesen bringt ziemlich viel, obwohl ich mich vorher nicht allzu positiv übers Lesen ausgedrückt habe (ich habe gesagt, dass das Schreiben dem Lesen ähnlich ist, aber um das Vielfache intensiver als das Schreiben, so dass es bei begrenzter Zeit besser ist, sich dem Schreiben und nicht dem Lesen zu widmen).

Also ist eigentlich eindeutig, dass "um das Vielfache" falsch ist (auch wenn Google das auf deutschen Websites findet). Das ist sicherlich darauf zurückzuführen, dass "viel" unbestimmt ist und sich deshalb mit dem bestimmten Artikel beißt.
Aber vielleicht ist das nur an sich falsch. Würde es aufhören, falsch zu sein, wenn man einen spezifischen Kontext schaffen würde? Zum Beispiel ein paar Sätze vorher würde stehen:

Ich glaube, durchs Lesen lernt man etwa 10-15 mal mehr Wortschatz als durch Gespräche.

Dieses "um das Vielfache" im Satz "... denn wer liest, hat um das Vielfache reicheren Wortschatz als jemand, der sich ausschließlich aufs Sprechen fokussiert" würde somit auf den Satz referieren, der eine Weile vorher (im vorherigen Absatz, ein paar Sätze vorher) aufgetreten ist - auf den Satz:

Ich glaube, durchs Lesen lernt man etwa 10-15 mal mehr Wortschatz als durch Gespräche

so dass es keinen Konflikt mehr gäbe zwischen dem bestimmten Artikel und dem unbestimmten "viel", da dieses "viel" eine Weile vorher ja konkretisiert ("10-15 mal") wurde.
Wäre "um das Vielfache" in diesem spezifischen Kontext richtig am Platz?

10-15mal ist m.E. immer noch sehr unbestimmt. Es umschließt das 10,1fache wie das 14,8fache, aber ohne einen Plural von Vielfachen zu meinen. M.E. immer noch "ein Vielfaches".

Es scheint als hätte das Problem eine einfache Lösung:

ein Vielfaches

ist irgendeines, aus einer großen Menge von möglichen Vielfachen. Das drückt der unbestimme Artikel aus.

das Vielfache

hingegen ist ein ganz bestimmtes solches. Ein Satz wie

Zwölf ist das Vielfache von drei.

ist zwar möglich, aber nur im Gegensatz zu "Nicht-Vielfachen", denn da wird nur das Gegensatzpaar als solches angesprochen:

Zwölf ist das Vielfache von drei, elf aber nicht.

Selbst das ist aber eher ungelenk. Die übliche Bedeutung, nämlich "X ist Y, das mit irgendwas multipliziert wird", wird aber nur durch den unbestimmten Artikel ausgedrückt, denn es gibt ja mehrere Vielfache (man kann Y mit allem möglichen multplizieren) und das vorliegende X ist nur eines davon.

Zwölf ist ein Vielfaches von drei, genau wie neun und fünfzehn.

Zurück zu dem Beispiel:

[...] das Schreiben dem Lesen ähnlich ist, aber um das Vielfache intensiver als das Schreiben [...]

Das geht deshalb nicht, weil man entweder ganz genau weiß, um wieviel besser das Schreiben als das Lesen ist, etwa so:

[...] das Schreiben dem Lesen ähnlich ist, aber um das 7,34-fache intensiver als das Schreiben [...]

dann wäre aber "das Vielfache" unangebracht und man müßte präzisieren: "um das Zweifache", "um das Fünffache" oder dergleichen.
Wenn man es aber nicht genau weiß, dann weiß man eben nur, daß man die Intensität von "Lesen" mit irgendeinem Wert multplizieren muß um die Intensität "Schreiben" zu erhalten - "irgendein" ist aber eines aus einer großen Menge von möglichen. Deshalb braucht es hier den unbestimmten Artikel.
Wenn "das Vielfache" vorher präzisisert wurde und "genau 10-15mal" bedeuten soll, dann ist "das Vielfache" zwar "eher richtig", aber sollte besser durch ein Demonstrativpronomen verdeutlicht werden: wir meinen dieses Vielfache, das wir vorher angesprochen und präzisiert haben:

... denn wer liest hat einen um dieses Vielfache reicheren Wortschatz als jemand, der sich ausschließlich aufs Sprechen fokussiert

(das "einen" zwischen "hat" und "um" fehlte im Original, gehört aber nicht zum Vielfachen, sondern zum Wortschatz)
Ob man "um" verwenden kann, ist eine davon unabhängige Frage. "um" verwendet man, um auszudrücken, wie sehr ("um wieviel") sich ein Wert vom anderen unterscheidet. Wenn A einen Kilometer geht und B "um 2 Kilometer mehr als A", dann geht B 3 Kilometer, bzw. "das Dreifache" von A". Er geht aber nur "um das Doppelte mehr" als A. Nämlich: er "geht mehr". Und zwar um wieviel? Um das Doppelte (das sind 2 Kilometer) mehr! Er geht auch "um ein Vielfaches" (nämlich ein Zweifaches) mehr, weil er ja auch einen kürzeren oder längeren Weg haben könnte (der, den er geht, ist vermutlich nicht der einzige Weg auf Erden) und das Vielfache, das er tatsächlich mehr gehen muß, nur eines unter vielen ist.

Diese Version wäre korrekt. Ich habe die Änderungen fett hervorgehoben:

Das Lesen bringt ziemlich viel, obwohl ich mich vorher nicht allzu positiv übers Lesen geäußert habe. (Ich habe gesagt, dass das Schreiben dem Lesen ähnlich ist, aber um ein Vielfaches intensiver als das Schreiben, so dass es bei begrenzter Zeit besser ist, sich dem Schreiben als dem Lesen zu widmen.)


Die Verben ausdrücken und äußern:
Ausdrücken: Man drückt sich nicht über etwas aus. Man verwendet dieses Verb, um die Qualität einer Formulierung zu bewerten.
Falsch: Karl drückt sich über die Vorgänge in der Nachbarschaft aus.
Richtig: Karl drück sich unklar aus.
Äußern: Dieses Verb bedeutet, dass man eine Aussage macht, und zu diesem Verb passt sehr gut, dass man eine Aussage über jemanden oder etwas macht. In den meisten Fällen fügt man noch hinzu, ob das eine zustimmende oder eine anlehnende Äußerung ist.
Richtig: Karl äußert sich negativ über die Vorgänge in der Nachbarschaft.

"Ich" großgeschrieben
Der Text in der Klammer ist ein vollständiger Satz. Daher wird der Satz vor der Klammer mit einem Punkt beendet und in der Klammer beginnt ein neuer Satz mit einem Großbuchstaben. Der Punkt, der ganz am Ende des Zitats stand, darf daher auch nicht hinter der schließenden Klammer stehen, sondern muss davor (also innerhalb der Klammer) stehen.

um ein Vielfaches
Wenn hier der bestimmte Artikel »das« (»um das Vielfache«) verwendet wist, dann wird damit ein ganz bestimmtes Vielfaches gemeint, also z.B. genau das Dreifache oder genau das Fünffache. Durch den bestimmten Artikel drückt man aus, das man ganz genau sagen kann, um welches Vielfache das Schreiben intensiver als das Lesen ist. Das kann man aber nur durch eine wissenschaftliche Studie feststellen, an der eine große Zahl von Versuchspersonen teilnehmen müsste, und ich vermute, dass selbst dann herauskommen wird, dass das Intensitätsverhältnis zwischen Lesen und Schreiben kein fixer Wert ist, sondern von vielen unterschiedlichen Einflüssen abhängt, so das es gar nicht möglich ist, anzugeben, um welchen Faktor genau das Schreiben intensiver als das Lesen ist.
Daher ist es das Vielfache hier nicht etwas, das bekannt, also bestimmt ist, sondern es ist einfach nur irgend ein Vielfaches, also unbestimmt und daher ist der bestimmte Artikel falsch und der unbestimmte ist richtig. Wegen des Wechsels der Bestimmtheit muss auch das adjektivische Substantiv selbst anders gebeugt werden, das heißt es bekommt eine andere Endung:

Adjektiv: vielfach
bestimmtes Substantiv: das Vielfache
unbestimmtes Substantiv: ein Vielfaches


und nicht → als
In dem zitierten Satz wird ein impliziter Vergleich mit einer absoluten Aussage verbunden:

impliziter Vergleich: Es ist besser, sich dem Schreiben zu widmen.
absolute Aussage: Man soll sich nicht dem Lesen widmen.

Das passt nicht zusammen. Abgesehen davon, dass es ein schlechter Rat ist, sich nicht dem Lesen zu widmen, und abgesehen davon, dass man gar nicht schreiben kann, ohne zu lesen, ist diese Verbindung auch aus sprachlichen Gründen sehr fragwürdig.
Wenn die Steigerungsform von gut (also »besser«) verwendet wird, macht man einen Vergleich. Manchmal ist das ein impliziter Vergleich, bei dem jener Teil, mit dem verglichen wird, weggelassen wird:

Die neue Kaffeesorte schmeckt viel besser. = Die neue Kaffeesorte schmeckt viel besser als die alte.

Sehr oft wird aber eine Sache explizit mit einer anderen verglichen, und dann muss das Wort als verwendet werden:

Sandra ist größer als Laura. Es ist besser, Sport zu machen, als auf dem Sofa zu hocken.

In dem zitierten Satz sollen ganz offensichtlich Lesen und Schreiben miteinander Verglichen werden, daher ist diese Variante richtig:

Es ist besser, sich dem Schreiben als dem Lesen zu widmen.




Was sollen die ganzen Ausführungen zu Dingen, die nicht gefragt waren (äußern/ausdrücken; Ich; und nicht als)? Das war doch alles nicht die Frage. Die Antwort zum Vielfachen wäre gut, aber geht im sonstigen Wust unter. In der Kürze liegt die Würze.

Danke für die Erklärung und zusätzliche Anmerkungen. Ich lerne immer gerne etwas Zusätzliches (so wie es in meinem Profil steht)
